# How to batch rename video files with quality information using python?

Tags: python, video-processing, opencv, batch-rename

I was trying to write a program to rename all the video files of a folder. I just wanted to add video quality or dimension like (720p) or (1080p) or something like that to the end of the current file name. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Python Projects\Practice\mm.py", line 17, in <module>
    os.rename(file_name, f'{file_title} ({height}p){file_extension}')
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Video 1.mp4' -> 'Video 1 (1080p).mp4'
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
from cv2 import cv2

os.chdir(r'F:\Python Projects\Practice\Temp Files')

for file_name in os.listdir():
    # Getting Video Resolution
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        f_string = str(f).split('\'')[1]
        video_path = f'F:\\Python Projects\\Practice\\Temp Files\\{f_string}'
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    # Getting the title
    file_title, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    os.rename(file_name, f'{file_title} ({height}p){file_extension}')
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this problem? Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Updated the error. Have a look now... :)

Comment: Try to explicitely close the file. Could be that carbage collection, auto closing, takes place after your rename.

Comment: @Mace Using `with open...` is the right way to have the file closed at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: @Mace I think the cv2.VideoCapture() is still open though I opened it using with. I'm not sure how to close a file manually, opened with cv2.VideoCapture. It would be better if you gave me a modified code with what you're telling. It would be helpful for me to find a quick solution.

Comment: Does `video.release()` at the end of the `with` block help?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille OMG! It worked! Both indented with 'with' block or after 'with' block works perfectly! Thanks a lot for helping me out! ❤

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)` opens your file as well. As this object continues to exist, the file is still open (even if it no longer is by your `open(...) as f:` once you exit the `with` block.)

So, you have to do it explicitely with:

```
video.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Tested. Use

```
video.release()
```

to close a file opened with cv2.

```
import os
from cv2 import cv2

os.chdir(r'F:\Python Projects\Practice\Temp Files')

for file_name in os.listdir():
    # Getting Video Resolution

    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    f_string = str(f).split('\'')[1]
    f.close()

    video_path = f'F:\\Python Projects\\Practice\\Temp Files\\{f_string}'
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    video.release()

    # Getting the title
    file_title, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    os.rename(file_name, f'{file_title} ({height}p){file_extension}')
```

Comment: This is same as what with open() does. Manually closing also gives the same error. :(

Comment: Sorry, you already mentioned cv2 could be the problem. Try it with release().

Comment: It worked perfectly with release(). Thanks a lot to both of you... ❤

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified the code and it works quite fine. I'm sharing my code here. If anyone becomes benefited from my code, it will be a matter of pride for me... :)

```
import os
from cv2 import cv2

video_folder = r'F:\Python Projects\Practice\Temp Files'
os.chdir(video_folder)

for file_name in os.listdir():
    # Getting video quality
    video_path = f'{video_folder}\\{file_name}'
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    width = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    video.release()

    # Getting title
    file_title, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    new_file_name = f'{file_title} ({width}p){file_extension}'

    # Renaming the file
    os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)

print('Rename Successful!')
```

Comment: Better without the f = open()  :-))